# Why does C++ CLI force classes to have variables in constructor method?

Tags: c++-cli

```
public ref class masterWeapon{

public :
    property int Slot {
        int get(){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    masterWeapon(){ 
    }
};

OSamp::masterWeapon mw();
int v = mw.Slot; //ERROR error C2228: left of '.Slot' must have class/struct/union
```

However following code ran fine :

```
public ref class masterWeapon{

public :
    property int Slot {
        int get(){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    masterWeapon(int useless){  
    }
};

OSamp::masterWeapon mw(231312);
int v = mw.Slot; //works fine
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does C++ CLI force classes to have variables in constructor method?

It doesn't, you just have an error in your code.

```
OSamp::masterWeapon mw();
```

The error message is slightly misleading; it is the line above that is causing the issue.  The compiler is telling you that `mw` is not an instance of an object. `mw` is interpreted as a prototype for a function which takes no arguments and returns an `OSamp::masterWeapon`.

The line should be rewritten as:

```
OSamp::masterWeapon mw;
```

Comment: This is **not** the most vexing parse. It's simply a function declaration. The most vexing parse is similar, but, as the link indicates, involves the use of an anonymous object as the sole constructor argument, which is parsed as a function declaration and not an object initialization. If you tell someone that `OSamp::masterWeapon mw();` is a function declaration they say "Oh, I see." If you tell them that `OSamp::masterWeapon mw(some_type());` is a function declaration they scratch their head.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, you're right.  I was in the process of editing that out when I was interrupted.  Thanks for reminding me.